# How to control RC Car or RC plane from Mobile device like iPhone and Android programmatically

Tags: java, android, iphone, ios, xcode

I am thinking to make an mobile app in Android and iPhone which will work as remote for RC car or RC plane. SO i need help for that. I don't have any thing in my mind that how to start it. Please Help me to make this application. If there are any articles or tutorials on this topic then kindly suggest me.
( Any suggestion Commonware ) ?

Comment: What type of plane? What type of transmission technology? This is a very broad question to be answered.

Comment: You will need to provide us some information first. WHat hardware do you plan on using? are you operaing mainly with android or iOS? what OS versions will you be using? we need information.

Comment: and what it seems like is that you want SO and it's users to be your research database. Instead of asking us for articles, you need to research some yourself (use google if you can). If you show us that you are willing to work for it, then maybe we will help you (no gaurantees).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to dig in : http://www.arduino.cc/ which is an open source platform for micro-controllers. It will let you build a small board that have access to LAN.
then you will build an android / ios application that will send `sockets` over an `IP` and `Port` to your micro-controller. My friend did it :)

Comment: Thanks SAmzz . That what i was asking for.